# Laradock: docker-compose.yml is invalid format (PORT[/PROTOCOL]) on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I try to follow the Laradock getting started tutorial on windows: http://laradock.io/getting-started/

I have the following tools:

```
Docker version: 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
git version: 2.30.2.windows.1
Windows 10 20H2(19042.867)
```

I get stuck on the step when trying to start the: `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`

Then I get these error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.proxy.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.proxy2.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]'
services.proxy.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.proxy2.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
...
services.sqs.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.sqs.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.traefik.ports value [':', ':', ':'] has non-unique elements
```

Only change I done to the repo is to add the env file and this line:

```
# Point to the path of your applications code on your host
APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../project-z/
```

I also created the folder `project-z`

I saw this text quote but didn´t understand it:

> Depending on the host’s operating system you may need to change the
> value given to COMPOSE_FILE. When you are running Laradock on Mac OS
> the correct file separator to use is :. When running Laradock from a
> Windows environment multiple files must be separated with ;.

But think it might be related to my issue and I need to update something to make it work on Windows.

Any idea what could be wrong? Since it almost out of the box I assume it´s something with my Windows environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution directly after posted this question.

It was very easy I forgot to add the "." before env when created the file.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1437